# I want to follow someone else's interesting question

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, tracking

I often run across questions that people have *just* asked and are of great interest to me.  I can mark them as favorite and go back to them, but I would rather have the ability to follow the question and have the answer emailed to me instead just like it happens on my own question(s).

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe to the questions RSS. There are many readers/services that can email updates to you.

Comment: But then would that not mean that over time, I would have hundreds of RSS feeds for SO alone?

Comment: Raj is right. It is a hell to manage. Also, questions are too important for RSS. I prefer email notification.

Comment: Another problem is that you can't subscribe to comments