# Notifications on someone else question: is there a way to get them?

Tags: feature-request, support

I have a question on some topic, and I found out that someone else already asked the same question. It turns out there is no answer yet, or the current answers are not good enough.
Is there a way for me to get all notifications of this question in my SE inbox? I basically would like to receive the same notifications that original asker receives.

I saw this question, ["I want to follow someone else's interesting question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20391/i-want-to-follow-someone-elses-interesting-question), where someone suggests using an RSS feed, but what I would really like is to just receive them on my SE inbox.

If there is no way of doing this please consider this question as a feature request.
I am not sure if setting a bounty on the question would achieve my goal, but even if it does it might be a bit "too expensive."

**Edit:**

It seems there is really no way of getting this kind of notifications. I hope it is safe to tag this question as [feature-request].

Something that could be added to this request is the possiblity for a user asking a question to prevent others from receiving these notifications, just in case someone does not really like this idea.

Comment: Related, and borderline duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20391/i-want-to-follow-someone-elses-interesting-question

Comment: @Daniel The OP linked the very same question and explained the difference (SE inbox vs. RSS feed).

Comment: @JYelton you know, I think I just saw the link and assumed it was the interesting question he wanted to follow and didn't even check.  Derp.

Comment: Hm, I've heard of a tool that lets you do this... I think it's called "Firesheep"? (That was a joke, please do not try it at home. (Your home or anyone else's.))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gets you somewhat there:

Set the question as a favorite, and you can be notified of changes to your favorite questions by way of your profile page.

Comment: +1 This may work. However it has a drawback, I put some "popular" questions on my favorites list from time to time, which may polute my SE inbox with some noise.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? I was just trying to do this and I cannot find any option on my profile page for notifications on favorite questions.

Comment: The notification appears as an indicator next to the "Favorites" tab on your profile page. There doesn't seem to be a way to actually see a summary of favorites changes at present (perhaps someone can point this out) but you can sort by recent activity.